# SwapExactTokensForETH is called instead of TransferFrom

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, bsc, pancakeswap

I developed a smart contract which calls PCS router V2 to get some data, however I don't know what I did to change the way it works and now when I interact with it via PancakeSwap the method called is from the router (SwapExactTokenForETH instead of using TransferFrom).

Does anyone know why I have this behaviour ? Why wouldn't pcs call transfer method anymore ?

Comment: We'd 100% need to see code to answer this. But `SwapExactTokensForETH` is one of the methods in the pancakeswap router contract. It sounds like everything is working to me.

Comment: It was a problem linked to my transfer that made it impossible to call. Everything is fine, thank you for your answer !